# one command | findstr and than string manipulation

Tags: powershell, jboss

I need a oneliner in PowerShell to get information from `jboss-cli`.

I have this already:

```
jboss-cli.bat -c --command="ls /deployment=application.war/subsystem=web" |
    findstr /IB "active-sessions="
```

output is:
`active-sessions=100` but now I only need the `100`. In `bash` I would pipe this to `awk`. But how should I do this in PowerShell?

Answer (score 0):

`findstr` is a tool for CMD. In PowerShell you'd use `Select-String` or a `Where-Object` filter.

```
jboss-cli.bat ... |
    Where-Object { $_ -match 'active-sessions=(\d+)' } |
    ForEach-Object { $matches[1] }
```

The regular expression match allows you to extract the submatch via the [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$matches`.

Comment: Or something like this: `(& jboss-cli.bat ...).tostring() -replace 'active-sessions=(\d+)', '$1'`

Comment: @n01d For that to work you'd need to keep the `findstr` call or change the replacement regex to something like `[\s\S]*active-sessions=(\d+)[\s\S]*`, otherwise the replacement wouldn't remove text befor or after the "active-sessions=" line.